# JQuery Accordion Anchor Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am attempting to add the following behavior to JQuery Accordion:

1) Activate a section of the accordion based on internal page links (`#section1`). This means if the user goes to URL `mypage.com/page.php#test` that I would use JS to activate that accordion section.

2) Make the headings of each section of the accordion copyable links to the url that would activate said section of the accordion. So if a user right clicks on the "section title" of the accordion and copied the link location it would put `mypage.com/page.php#test` on the users' clipboard.

---

I have 1) figured out, but it is code of my own writing. I was messing around with the `navigation:true` option but was not having any luck. If someone would care to point me in the right direction I would prefer using the author's code to my own, but if not, no biggie as this is completed.

2) is where I am at a loss. It seems that JQuery accordion is binding code to clicking events anywhere in the header of the accordion section. This seems to make it impossible to give the user the copy link location functionality I would like.

My HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
   <article class="std_page_content">
    <h3><a id="#test">Test</a></h3>
    <div>
       test
    </div>
   </article>
   .....additional accordion sections....
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({header : "h3", heightStyle : "content", /*Allows full collapse*/collapsible: true, /*collapses sections*/ active:false, navigation:true});

var theUrl = window.location.href;
var hashValue = theUrl.contains("#") ? theUrl.split('#')[1] : null;

if(hashValue != null)
{
    //open the corresponding accordion section
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your anchor tags an href attribute:

```
<h3><a id="#test" href="#test">Test</a></h3>
```

Update: If you'd like the link to cover the entire accordion header, you can put the `<h3>` tag inside the anchor tag, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/3tGYB/1/

```
<div id="accordion">
  <article class="std_page_content">
    <a id="#test" href="#test" class="header"><h3>Test</h3></a>
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

And of course change your javascript:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({header : "a.header" /*plus other options*/});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. That would just make it link back to itself. Does this have something to do with the `navigation` option?

Comment: If you add the href attribute to your link, you'll be able to right-click and copy the link address, which is your stated second goal.  As you mentioned, jQuery UI handles the clicking events in the accordion, including preventing the url from updating.  You can check it out on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3tGYB/

Comment: This works okay. The only issue is that you have to be right over the heading for it to copy/paste. I am going to continue to look for a solution that will allow copy/paste when you are over any part of the "heading" of the section. Thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer to allow copy/paste for the entire section header.

Comment: Ah, thanks for stating the obvious. I will try this out as soon as I hunt down a bug I am looking for, and will accept as appropriate. Thank you!